# Filter list for many pie charts and removing them

Tags: dc.js

I've got 2 pie charts with data like:

```
data: [
    {diseaseType: 'Cancer', diseaseDetails: 'Lung cancer', quantity: 100},
    {diseaseType: 'Diebetes', diseaseDetails: 'Unspecific', quantity: 650},
    {diseaseType: 'Cancer', diseaseDetails: 'Breast cancer', quantity: 80}
  ]
```

i'm tying to get list of filters and able to remove them by user like (it's only controlled test code):

```
this.diseasePieChart.filters().splice(0, 1)
dc.renderAll()
```

it's updating first chart, but second (connected with first) not, it's stay like it was before remove filter.

Second chart i'm rendering like this:

```
self.diseasePieChart.on('filtered.monitor', function (chart) {
// create dimensions etc and render second chart
}
```

I also tried to do again crossfilter(data) after filter remove. When i'm calling `dc.filterAll` all filters are reset.

thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct entry points for changing filters are [chart.filter()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filter__anchor) or [chart.replaceFilter()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#replaceFilter__anchor), depending on whether you are trying to toggle individual items or change the entire array of filters at once.

As you found out, manipulating the array of filters inside the chart might affect the way the chart draws, but it won't convey the change to the crossfilter dimension and the other charts.

Note that as documented in the link above, the accepted type for the parameter for each of these functions is a little surprising:

> The filter parameter can take one of these forms:
>
> - A single value: the value will be toggled (added if it is not present in the current filters, removed if it is present)
> - An array containing a single array of values (`[[value,value,value]]`): each value is toggled
> - When appropriate for the chart, a dc filter object such as
>
>   - dc.filters.RangedFilter for the dc.coordinateGridMixin charts
>   - dc.filters.TwoDimensionalFilter for the heat map
>   - dc.filters.RangedTwoDimensionalFilter for the scatter plot
> - `null`: the filter will be reset using the resetFilterHandler

So if you want to get the array, remove an item, and then set it back, you could either:

```
var filters = chart.filters().slice(0); // copy the array of filters
filters.splice(0,1)
chart.replaceFilter([filters])
   .redrawGroup();
```

or (using the toggle feature):

```
chart.filter(chart.filters()[0])
    .redrawGroup();
```

Note that you usually want to redraw, not render, after changing a filter. This will allow the animated transitions to display, and is a little bit quicker.

Also, [chart.redrawGroup](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#redrawGroup__anchor) is the same as `dc.redrawAll()` but it's a little safer in case you have more chart groups in the future.

Comment: it works ! Thanks a lot for solution and explanation !

Comment: can i ask something else ? it's too small problem to make new topic. I'm trying to append <icon name="..."> to htmlLegend like: .legend(dc.htmlLegend().container(this.$refs.sampleTypeChartLegend).legendText(function(d, i) {
                        return d.name + ' - ' + d.data
                    })) . I tried to do .append('icon').attr('name','...') but there is error, while adding it's to text of course it's rendering like a text

Comment: Too complicated for a comment! I can't read code like that. Also you'd have to tell me what the error is.